why BleDevice disconnects automatically with android?
Some times when i connect to the ble device, it automatically disconnects after connecting.
I tried to disconnect it before connecting. It shows me connection success and in between shows message of disconnect. Some times it will not shows message but almost shows disconnect message.

Please add more details. What "messages" are you referring to?

The ‘low energy’ claim in BLE must be taken seriously. Many devices, especially battery-operated devices, terminate a connection to save energy when data is no longer being transmitted.
If you have a HCI log it is generally quite easy to find out why the connection was disconnected. The disconnect message contains a ‘Reason’ parameter.
